# How to enforce web browser to track user location through django?

Tags: django

I want to deny access users to my web application when they are not in the company area ,so I can to enforce web browser to track the user location through django?

Comment: You could ask for access to the location, but the user could refuse to give.

Comment: lookup 'fetch user location with javascript'

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

- Do this in the Web browser via JavaScript.  You can receive the coordinates of the user there.  The user has to agree, but you can refuse to show the content if they don't give the information - details would depend heavily on how your Web site works
- If you want to limit it to specific offices and they have static IPs, you can restrict traffic to a list of predefined IPs in Django.  This answer has some good approaches for that:  [Authenticate by IP address in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383540/authenticate-by-ip-address-in-django)
- You can get the IP of the request and do a geo-lookup on the IP and use that to restrict the traffic.  You likely will want to do this using middleware.  Please note that this may add quite a bit of delay, so you likely will want to remember where a certain IP is, at least for a while, in some cache or datastore