# How to prevent Postman like tool to access the Django rest api ? and able to access only from Native APP

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have  a API Code like this

```
class TEST(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    try:
        taxdtl = views
        jsondata = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        request.session['Entity_gid'] = 1
        lj_sales_fav_pdct = taxdtl.sales_fav_product(request)
        test = lj_sales_fav_pdct.content
        return Response(json.loads(test))
    except:
        return Response({"MESSAGE": "ERROR_OCCURED"})
```

and i have  a authendicate token like this

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
),
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', )
```

}

But when user can in debugger mode F12 can see all data's and able to see all data including Token.

Suggest me how to prevent this.

The API must be access only from the Python views of the Native website, and not form ARC or POST Man like tool.

Answer (score 2):

I think its not really possible to do exactly what You ask.

When You run server with backend application, and this app can be external access, 'everybody' can send request and if its valid get response (POST Man tool, custom scripts etc.). Also all data stored in headers, local storage etc. will be visible for anybody who gonna hit f12 :/.

What You can do:

- use one time auth token
- use auth token with very short use time
- encrypt data inside auth token
- run everything local

Cheers

fenrir

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Fenrir, making an app publicly accessible means anyone can make a request to it. However, what you can do is ensure the caller is authorized before allowing them to actually access your API. I see two solutions you should consider:

- Enforcing user authentication (with [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/))
- Enforcing IP restrictions

  - see [Authenticate by IP address in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383540/authenticate-by-ip-address-in-django)
  - this can also be achieved through services like AWS CloudFront & WAF