# Django: How to limit ip address or ip range for users?

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to limit the ip address of the user from which he can access the website? I found an answer that shows how we can get the ip address of the user, and I thought of adding a field on the User model that would contain the address or range from which the user can access the website and then when a request from a user comes, I'd check his IP address and prevent/allow him to access the website.

But is there a more elegant way that would require less work? I've found some packages that seem to work with older Django versions, but they don't quite meet my needs. What I would need is basically have the admin be able to limit the ip range for each and every user from the admin panel. Is there a way to do such a thing? Besides the method I have described?

Comment: Does that help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383540/authenticate-by-ip-address-in-django

Comment: thank you very much! I shall try this approach!

Comment: Try to look on existing topics first in the future :)